# How can update the count down time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a count down time by using directive and also I have to add some css styles like fade-out when time is changing, my problem is in the html binding the time is not changing but in console it is changing.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<count-down-timer count-down-time=5000></count-down-timer>
 {{userCountDownTime}}
</body>
```

Here is my JS code:

```
app.directive('countDownTimer', function () {
return {
restrict: 'E',
replace: true,
link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
  scope.userCountDownTime = attr.countDownTime;
  initiate();
  function initiate() {
    console.log("initiated")
    var myVar = setInterval(decrement, 1000);
  };

  function decrement() {
    console.log("decrement");
    scope.userCountDownTime--;
    console.log(scope.userCountDownTime);
    return;
  }
}
 }});
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval This way angular "knows" to update the view if any parameters bound to it were changed in the callback function by triggering a digest cycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/FSOtUYcoPhLEwp5paNin?p=preview

```
.directive('countDownTimer', function ($interval) {
return {
restrict: 'E',
replace: true,
link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
  scope.userCountDownTime = attr.countDownTime;
  initiate();
  function initiate() {
    console.log("initiated")
    var myVar = $interval(decrement, 1000);
  };
```

You need add $interval service which is a  wrapper over window.setInterval
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Answer (score 1):

You need to notify angularJS that something has changed. You need to call `$scope.$apply`. You can do it safely by using `$interval`.

```
app.directive('countDownTimer', function ($interval) {
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.userCountDownTime = attr.countDownTime;

      $interval(decrement, 1000);

      function decrement() {
          scope.userCountDownTime--;
      }
    }
}});
```

EDIT: Modified to use $interval instead of $timeout.

Comment: No point or extra value in calling `$timeout` when you should simply trigger the function with `$interval`

Comment: Much better now :)

Answer (score 0):

So your directive could be changed with

```
app.directive('countDownTimer', [ '$interval', function ( $interval ) {
return {
restrict: 'E',
replace: true,
link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
  scope.userCountDownTime = attr.countDownTime;
  initiate();
  function initiate() {
    console.log("initiated")
    var myVar = $interval(decrement, 1000);
  };

  function decrement() {
    console.log("decrement");
    scope.userCountDownTime--;
    console.log(scope.userCountDownTime);
    return;
  }
}
 }}]);
```